# mysql inserting data on different colums when it doesn't exist on the other table

Tags: mysql

so I'm try to insert a string on a column if it doesn't exist, I'm not quite sure on the query that I'll use but I'm trying to insert it, here's an sample.

```
table1                  table2
|  col1  |    col2  |  | id  | data1 |
|:-----------------:|  |:-----------:|
|        |          |  |  1  | sample|
|:-------|---------:|  |:----|------:|
```

here what approach/query I'll use, if the data I'm trying to insert in col1 is existing on table2 which is sample then insert it on col1 but when it does not exist on table2 I'll just place it on col2

Comment: Where does the string you're trying to insert come from?

Comment: from a placeholder '?'

Answer (score 1):

Use `IF()` expressions for the values to be inserted into each column.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
VALUES (IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE data1 = ?), ?, ''),
        IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE data1 = ?), '', ?))
```